# ¿Por qué algunas interjecciones en español acaban en 'h'?

Tags: ortografía, letras, interjecciones

Estoy leyendo en el diccionario de Covarrubias (1611) lo siguiente:

> En vocablos castellanos jamás la 'h' se pone en fin de dicción.

Aunque seguidamente cita dos excepciones: *[ah](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1GNbcOe)* y *[bah](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4mX1tFr)*. Buscando en el DLE palabras que terminen en 'h' veo que, efectivamente, la lista solo contiene interjecciones del estilo (se añaden otras como *[eh](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ERYOg9R)*, *[oh](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QwpIHLI)*, *[uh](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b1OpfUP)*), palabras importadas de otros idiomas y palabras formadas a partir de nombres propios extranjeros, como *Koch*.

Fascinante resulta la explicación de Covarrubias acerca de la 'h' final de las interjecciones:

> [Se añade la 'h'] por extender el sonido de la 'a', y mostrar el afecto grande de la pasión.

¿Cuál es la explicación actual de esa 'h' final? ¿Sigue siendo para representar el alargamiento de la vocal en la interjección? ¿Cuál es su origen? ¿Se usa una 'h' para alargar sonidos vocálicos en otras palabras además de estas interjecciones?

La única interjección que contiene una etimología en el DLE es *bah*:

> ```
> Del lat. vāh; cf. lat. mediev. ba.
> ```

Lo cual da a entender que esa 'h' final podría haber existido ya en latín, aunque en el Diccionario de Autoridades veo que "ah" (por ejemplo) se usaba poco y equivalía a "ay", mientras que la más usada era "ha".

Answer (score 3):

La mayoría de estas palabras viene de latín, en cual la *h* sí era pronunciada, tal como en castellano antiguo:

- [ah](https://www.spanishetym.com/term/ah) ← [ah](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=ah) (← aha)
- oh ← [oh](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=oh)<sup>1</sup>
- [bah](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?bah) ← [vah](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=vah)
- aha ← ehem?<sup>2</sup>
- ahaha ← ahahe<sup>2</sup>

Dado esto, parece credible que las otras palabras (*eh*, *uh* etc) deben sus ortografías a la influencia de las palabras ya existentes.

Creo que la explicación:

> "por extender el sonido de la 'a', y mostrar el afecto grande de la pasión."

(que también a veces se da para explicar la ortografía de las interjecciones italianas<sup>3 4</sup>) es retroactiva. Es decir, después de que la *h* ya no se pronunciaba, la *-h* terminal ortográfica se asoció con interjecciones, y por eso el efecto emocional en este contexto (no al contrario).

---

<sup>**1.** Terreros y Pando (G-O) (1787)</sup>
<sup>**2.** Rosal (1611)</sup>
<sup>**3.** [*The Popular Educator: A complete Encyclopædia... Vol. III*](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3929/complete-list-of-nonforeign-spelling-exceptions-involving-the-use-of-the-letter/9221#9221), Cassell, Petter and Galpin (Lessons in Italian - IV, P.148)</sup>
<sup>**4.** En francés y italiano, esta *h* también es silenciosa pero todavía preservada en sus interjecciones cognadas:</sup>
  <sup>• **Italiano:** [ah](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ah/), [eh](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/eh/), [òh](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/oh/), [uh](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/uh/), [bah](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bah/), [ahi, ahimè, ehi, ohi, ohimè, deh, doh](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3929/complete-list-of-nonforeign-spelling-exceptions-involving-the-use-of-the-letter/9221#9221)</sup>
  <sup>• **Francés:** [ah](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ah), [eh](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/eh), [oh](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oh), ouh, [bah](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bah)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi mera opinión sin bases, fuentes ni fundamentos

Normalmente he entendido que agregar "H" al final es para indicar la extensión del sonido y no malinterpretarlo con los artículos que usan dicha letra o otras palabras similares

ejemplos

> a, ha, y ah ,
>
> > a indica dirección
> >     ha del verbo hacer
> >     ah expresión
>
> e , he y eh
>
> > e es conjunción
> >     he del verbo hecho
> >     eh expresion
>
> o, oh
>
> > o es una disyuntiva
> >     oh expresión

en general, creo que la "H" o múltiples "H" también indican la extensión, pudiendo asi exagerar.

y son mas expresiones que palabras, por lo que se usan en el trascripción lenguaje expresivo que en el descriptivo